# How to mock parent class method for Unit Test in Angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am writing a Unit test for a class which extends another class and call parent method at runtime. Since I don't want to deal with parent class is there any way to mock that method call ? I have tried multiple ways but nothing in working

```
class A {
   doSomething(){
       console.log(123);
     }
}

class B extends A {
    work(){
      this.doSomething();
  }
}
```

How I can mock this function call and return something else in Unit Test for Class B ?

I have tried the following :

```
spyOn(b,'doSomething');

spyOn(Object.getPrototypeOf(b),'doSomething');
```

There are no errors it just keeps calling the original parent method

Comment: It would be nice to show us, what exactly you have tried so far and what the specific errors where.

Comment: Updated @Erbsenkoenig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do, but I would not recommend it, is to stub the parent method itself inside you class B.

I would not recommend this approach because you would stub something inside the Class you are unit testing. I would rather stub things, that are being done inside this parent method.

But if you really want to stub that method, you could do something along those lines:

```
describe('DataService', () => {
    let service: DataService;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({ providers: [DataService] });
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
      service = TestBed.get(DataService); // would be inject in newer angular versions
    });

    it('test case 2', () => {
      spyOn(service as any, 'parentMethod').and.returnValue(5);
      expect(service.getData()).toEqual(5);
    });
});
```

where `DataService` would be

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService extends AbstractDataService {
  constructor() {
    super();
   }

  getData() {
    return this.parentMethod();
  }
}
```

and `AbstractDataService`

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AbstractDataService {
  constructor() { }

  parentMethod() {
    console.log('parent method');
    return null;
  }
}
```

Works for **components**, too. But again: **it is not advisable to mock methods inside the object under test!!**

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
    let component: AppComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [AppComponent, AbstractAppComponent],
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
            bootstrap: [AppComponent]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    it('should mock method', () => {
      spyOn(component as any, 'abstractMethod').and.returnValue(10);

      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(component.myMethod()).toEqual(10);
    });    
});
```

---

[Stackblitz with test cases for both service and component](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-extended-classes?file=app/abstract-data.service.ts)

Comment: makes sense, but the only difference is in my case its a Component not a service. And this approach doesn't work when you try to stub a method from the parent class of a component. Can you help with that ?

Comment: it works the same way. instead of spying on the service you will spy on the method inside your component.

Comment: service = TestBed.get(DataService); this won't work for component. I have tried spyOn(component,'parentMethod'); but it call the original method only

Comment: When you work with a TestBed, you will get your component instance. And you can stub methods on that, just like on you services

Comment: Have a look at the stackblitz, i've included a component version.

Comment: yea, slackblitz is throwing error for some reason. Anyway its working as you suggested but in my case I tried the same it works when i call like component.method() but when it is getting called indirectly inside a subscription block it again goes to the original method

Comment: well it depends where your call is, how you component looks like and so on. You've asked a quite general question and my answer should give you the general idea. If you still have troubles getting your actual use case working, I suggest you create a stackblitz yourself where you are trying to get your test setup and if you are stuck you should ask an explicit question about that issue/error and post it again including a link to your stackblitz. Otherwise it is not possible to help you accordingly.

Comment: Yea makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Once you have a stackblitz where your stuck, feel free to link me to the issue. You can also fork the stackblitz and play around with it as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks, the issue is fixed now. The method call was inside a subscribe block of an external service which was not mocked so for some reason it was taking time there and since I have mock the service it is calling the mock version only